# Show that the set $\{(x,y): xy=1, x>0\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am new to analysis and I'm afraid my approach is not detailed enough.

Here is my attempt:

"To show $S=\{(x,y)\in E^2: xy=1, x>0\}$ , $S\subset E^2$ is a closed set, we can show that $S^c$ is an open set.

Let $p\in S^c$. Then there exists an open ball of center $p$ and radius $\epsilon$, call it $B_\epsilon(p)$.

Let $q\in B_\epsilon(p)$. To ensure that $q\in S^c$, choose  $\epsilon =\min\{d(p,z), z\in S\}$.

Is this enough?

Comment: For some basic information on how to proper typeset mathematics at this site see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also by $E^2$ do you mean $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I assume that is what the book means yes.

Comment: what about what you wrote used anything about $S$? Could you not write the same thing about any set?

Comment: I just tried this approach on a similar problem, and I see what you mean...

Comment: @mucciolo It's quite common, $E$ stands for Euclidean space (I believe).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not enough, because: (a) You don’t know that the minimum exists (though surely there is the infimum), and (b) Even if you replace the minimum with infimum, how are you sure that this infimum is nonzero?

The correct proof would take the point $(x,y)$ such that $x\gt 0, xy\ne 1$, then if you set $\epsilon=|1-xy|$, due to continuity of $(x,y)\to xy$ there is an open ball $B$ containing $(x,y)$ such that, for $(z,t)\in B$, $|zt-xy|\lt\epsilon$... but then $|1-zt|\ge|1-xy|-|zt-xy|\gt\epsilon-\epsilon=0$, i.e. $zt\ne 1$ on the whole $B$.

A more advanced way to rephrase the same proof here is to note that, in the continuous map $f:(x,y)\to xy$, we have the inverse image $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ of the closed set $\{1\}$, which is closed. Consequently, $S$ is closed as an intersection of that closed set with the closed half-plane $x\ge 0$.

Comment: ach sorry, I missed this while i was typing up mine. +1

Comment: If the infimum was zero, wouldn't that mean that p=z which is impossible since p is in S and z is in $S^c$?

Comment: nevermind I realize my mistake

Comment: @user491874: To my understanding, the 2nd paragraph is to show $S^c$ is open with $x>0$. However, should we show that under $x \leq 0$ as well?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\vec{x}_n$ be a sequence of points in $S$ converging to some $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2)$ in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, we may rewrite 
$$
\vec{x}_n=\left(x_n,\frac{1}{x_n}\right)
$$
If $\vec{x}_n$ is to converge to a this finite vector $\vec{x}$, we have the following condition
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\vec{x}_n=\vec{x}\iff |x_1-x_N|+|1/x_N-x_2|<\epsilon
$$
for given epsilon and corresponding $N$. Note immediately we can see that $x_n$ canot be converging to $0$, or the second term blows up. Note also that this means that
$$
x_n\to x_1
$$
just ignoring the second positive term. Then
$$
\frac{1}{x_n}\to \frac{1}{x_1}
$$
since $x$ is nonzero and the function $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous at nonzero $x$. Thus 
$$
x_2=1/x_1\implies \vec{x}=(x_1,1/x_1)\in S
$$
and $S$ contains its limit points.

Comment: qbert. A question. Let $(x_n,y_n)$ converge to $(x,y)$.limit $x_n$ to $x$ , $y_n$ to $y$. $x_ny_n=1$. Take the limit: $1=\lim (x_ny_n)= (\lim x_n)(\lim y_n)=xy$, hence limit is in $S$.Your thoughts?

Comment: @PeterSzilas that sounds fine!

Comment: qbert.Thanks.Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be the function that sends $(x,y)$ to $xy$. It is a continuous function hence the pre-image $A:=f^{-1}(\{1\})$ of the closed set $\{1\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

$B:= [0,+\infty)\times [0,+\infty)$ is also a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

The intersection of two closed sets is closed so $S=A\cap B$ is closed.

Using this kind of techniques is often useful or sets defined by equations such as in your case.

Comment: You should probably define $\mathbb R^+$; I would interpret it as the set of positive reals, which is obviously not what you want here.

Comment: Very nice answer, Mathieu.+1

Comment: You are right, I will add it.